# Emitting Array of int with QT Signal Results in uninitialized array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I've declared a signal in QT like this:

```
signals:
 void onResult(int,int[],int,int);
```

and a slot:

```
public slots:
void onBinarySearchComplete(int valueToSearchFor, int array[], int  arraySize, int valueIndex); //this slot is connected to the onResult of the BinarySearch class.
```

I'm declaring the array as a global object in my MainWindow class.

```
 int* m_array;
```

and dynamically allocating its memory later,

```
//create a random array to search.
 int arraySize = 50;
 m_array = new int[arraySize];
```

I then pass the array to the BinarySearch Object, which is also globally declared.

```
 //call the search
 int returnVal= s->search(searchValue,m_array,arraySize); //the binarysearch class will emit the onResult signal when the search is complete.
```

Inside my BinarySearch Object, I'm sorting the array, and then doing a search inside of the array for an element. 
I can print the array to qDebug() just before I call emit.

```
//this is the code that emits the signal in my BinarySearch class//
 qDebug()<<"Printing Array Just Before Emit";
 printArrayToDebug(array,arraySize);//the array is correct here!
 emit onResult(valueToSearchFor,array,arraySize,halfWayIndex);
```

At that point, the array contains the elements I've put in it, and it's ordered. However, when the array is received in the slot, the array appears to be new, and filled with nonsense.

```
//This is the slot the receives the signal in my MainWindow class//
void MainWindow::onBinarySearchComplete(int valueToSearchFor, int  array[], int arraySize, int valueIndex){

//this array appears uninitialized!
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){

    qDebug()<<array[i];
}
```

I was under the impression that C++ would pass array as int * in this case, and that this would still work. Is that incorrect? If so, how should I properly pass this array around between these objects?

Comment: I'm currious; why would you use old-school C arrays (that decay to pointers when passed as arguments, don't know their size & can't be resized) when you could be using `std::vector` instead?

Comment: I studied C in the late 90's in college and switched to C# around 2003 - so I've never really studied C++ directly. I had seen std::vector, but using an array of ints here seemed like a valid use to me. I mean, that's how I would do it in C# since it's literally an array of integers and it's not going to change size once the application is started. Do people not use int[] anymore?

Comment: I do not see any problems in the statement you made, only you have done it with the C style, and it works. I have a doubt: I see that it declares the `m_array` variable and initializes it, but when you emit the signal you send the `array` variable, you could show how you created the variable array.